# GWT, ListHandler<List<String>> columnSortHandler does not sort properly

Tags: java, gwt, sorting, celltable

I got these code:

```
           ListHandler<List<String>> columnSortHandler = new ListHandler<List<String>>(
                    list);
            columnSortHandler.setComparator(nameColumn,
                    new Comparator<List<String>>() {
                      public int compare(List<String> o1, List<String> o2) {
                        if (o1 == o2) {
                          return 0;
                        }

                        // Compare the name columns.
                        if (o1 != null) {
                          return (o2 != null) ? o1.get(0).compareTo(o2.get(0)) : 1;
                        }
                        return -1;
                      }
                    });

                table.addColumnSortHandler(columnSortHandler);
```

When sorting column contains iPhone 1, iPhone 2, iPhone 3... then it sorts correctly ie, iPhone 1, iPhone 2, iPhone 3  for ascending & iPhone 3, iPhone 2, iPhone 1 for decending

But when sorting column contains:

1.92 MP

 3.15 MP AF 0.31 MP

 3.2 MP

 5 MP AF and flash

 1.3 MP

 1.3 MP
 
2 MP (rear); 0.3 MP (front)

 1.92 MP AF with flash (rear)

it follows no correct order, it didn't even put the 2 "1.3 MP" cell next to each other. The correct order for the above list should be:
 
1.3 MP
 
1.3 MP
 
1.92 MP
 
1.92 MP AF with flash (rear)
 
2 MP (rear); 0.3 MP (front)
 
3.15 MP AF 0.31 MP
 
3.2 MP
 
5 MP AF and flash

Is there anything wrong with the code above?

Answer (score 0):

As the author of website said the `java sorting algorithm` is based on `ASCII`.It never works as a human thinks. :) rude but fact.

**People sort strings with numbers differently than software does.**

Use [The Alphanum Algorithm](http://www.davekoelle.com/alphanum.html)

In the above link [download](http://www.davekoelle.com/alphanum.html) `AlphanumComparator.java` and use it.

Comment: @Baadshah How does the sorting of numbers explain Tom's issue with not putting the "1.3 MP" cells next to each other?  I agree that "1", "2", and "10" will sort in the order "1, 10, 2" using an ASCII sort, but this doesn't explain Tom's problem.

Comment: @Tom I think your problem is that you're using the "==" operator when comparing `String` values ... you need to use `String#compareTo` (in fact, I'm not sure why you're writing your own comparator, since the `String#compareTo` will suffice).

Comment: @andy are you sure that compareTo will give what tom is asking even with numbers in string..?

Comment: @Baadshah `String#compareTo` should work with the example strings that Tom has identified. It won't work for "1", "2", and "10" however.

Answer (score 0):

I also add `o1.get(0).compareTo(o2.get(0))==0` into the code as what Any King suggested, but the sorting is still very messy.

```
ListHandler<List<String>> columnSortHandler = new ListHandler<List<String>>(
                list);
        columnSortHandler.setComparator(nameColumn,
                new Comparator<List<String>>() {
                  public int compare(List<String> o1, List<String> o2) {
                    if (o1.get(0).compareTo(o2.get(0))==0) {
                      return 0;
                    }

                    // Compare the name columns.
                    if (o1 != null) {
                      return (o2 != null) ? o1.get(0).compareTo(o2.get(0)) : 1;
                    }
                    return -1;
                  }
                });

            table.addColumnSortHandler(columnSortHandler);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is

```
ListHandler<List<String>>
```

& not the java sorting algorithm cos look at Gwt Sample http://gwt.googleusercontent.com/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwCellTable, it sort the address beautifully & the code use very simple compare. look at sample gwt code for sorting address

```
 addressColumn.setSortable(true);
addressColumn.setDefaultSortAscending(false);
sortHandler.setComparator(addressColumn, new Comparator<ContactInfo>() {
  @Override
  public int compare(ContactInfo o1, ContactInfo o2) {
    return o1.getAddress().compareTo(o2.getAddress());
  }
});
```